# Creating summary dataframe? ("Collapsing" data in to similar months)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a .csv with lots of data, generally laid out like this:

```
Customer    City    Month      Amount
Wayne E    Gotham   January    111
Wayne E    Gotham   January    222
Wayne E    Chicago  March      392
Wayne E    Buffalo  June       2928
Clark K    Krypton  January    100
Clark K    Amman    February   200
Clark K    Detroit  February   300
```

I'm trying to create a summary dataframe, that lists each Customer, then the unique cities they're in, and then `sum` the `Amount` for that month.

So for the above, I'd like my output to look like:

```
Customer    City    January February    March   April   May    June    ...    December
Wayne E    Gotham   333                 
Wayne E    Chicago                      392         
Wayne E    Buffalo                                             2928
Clark K    Krypton  100                 
Clark K    Amman            200             
Clark K    Detroit          200
```

So far I've been able to get the unique customers and cities, but am struggling on how to populate the month columns.  I am not even sure I'm setting up my summary dataframe in the best way, so have hit a wall thinking about it.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv", encoding='cp1252')
customers = df["Customer"].unique()
cities = df["City"].unique()

summary_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Assured","Facility", "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September", "October", "November","December"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `pivot` ?

```
df.pivot_table(index=['Customer','City'],columns='Month',values='Amount').reindex(columns=['January','February','March','April',   'May','June']).fillna('').reset_index()
Out[83]: 
Month Customer     City January February March April May  June
0       ClarkK    Amman              200                      
1       ClarkK  Detroit              300                      
2       ClarkK  Krypton     100                               
3       WayneE  Buffalo                                   2928
4       WayneE  Chicago                    392                
5       WayneE   Gotham   166.5
```

Comment: Aha!  With all the time I spend in Excel/VBA I'm disappointed I didn't think of a pivot table myself.  Thanks very much for your quick answer, that is exactly what I was looking for :D

Comment: @BruceWayne yw :-) happy coding my friend